# how to find current month's thurdays in php

Tags: php, date

I have tried to get the current week thursday's date using the code below

```
date('m/d/y',strtotime('thursday this week'));
```

As the above how can i get current months all thursday dates in php.

Comment: Actually in my application i am using one calendar based products. In that i have to show only the current month thurdays products. So i  asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your dates like this:

```
$sDay   = 'Thursday';
$rgTime = array_filter(
   range(strtotime('first day of this month'), strtotime('last day of this month'), 3600*24),
   function($iTime) use ($sDay)
   {
      return date('l', $iTime) == $sDay;
   });
```

Alternative way to get `$rgTime` will be:

```
$rgNums = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];
$rgTime = [];
$sDay   = 'Thursday';
foreach($rgNums as $sNum)
{
   $iTime = strtotime($sNum.' '.$sDay.' of this month');
   if(date('m', $iTime)==date('m'))
   {
      //this check is needed since not all months have 5 specific week days
      $rgTime[]=$iTime;
   }
}
```

-now, if you want to get specific format, like `Y-m-d`, that will be:

```
$rgTime = array_map(function($x)
{
   return date('Y-m-d', $x);
}, $rgTime);
```

*Edit*

If you want to have several week days, it's also easy. For first sample that will be:

```
$rgDays = ['Tuesday', 'Thursday'];
$rgTime = array_filter(
   range(strtotime('first day of this month'), strtotime('last day of this month'), 3600*24),
   function($iTime) use ($rgDays)
   {
      return in_array(date('l', $iTime), $rgDays);
   });
```

Comment: hi firend.. it worked... how can i get in the combination of both thursdays and thuesday..

Comment: First, you should specify that in your question.

Comment: ya i found answer.. thanks... i have used same for tuesdays.. and i merged both arrays. i got current months tuesday and thurdays...

Comment: @mangala I've already updated. You don't need to merge arrays, you can specify your days in `$rgDays` array

Answer (score 2):

It is advisable to make use of the improved date and time abilities that came with PHP 5.3.0. Namely, the [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/dateperiod) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/dateinterval) classes.

```
<?php

$start    = new DateTime('first thursday of this month');
$end      = new DateTime('first day of next month');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1W');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval , $end);

foreach ($period as $date) {
  echo $date->format('c') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Edit**

More complex filtering can be done in a variety of ways, but here is a simple approach to showing every Tuesday and Thursday in the month.

```
...
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
...
foreach ($period as $date) {
  if (in_array($date->format('D'), array('Tue', 'Thu'), TRUE)) {
      echo $date->format('c') . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. Should work :)

```
    <?
    $curMonth = date("m");
    $start = strtotime("next Thursday - 42 days");
    for ($i=1; $i < 15; $i++){
        $week = $i*7;
        if (date("m",strtotime("next Thursday - 42 days + $week days")) == $curMonth ){
            $monthArr[] = date("m/d/y",strtotime("next Thursday - 42 days + $week days"));
        }
    }


print_r($monthArr);

?>
```

[WORKING CODE](http://codepad.org/NAb0eLPS)